# How to make a css animation like this?

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions, css-animations

I want to know how to make this kind of animation with css:
https://www.maman-corp.com/solutions
when you scroll to the image with worker the image is going from 0% width to 100% with transition.

Answer (score 2):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  background: tomato;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  -webkit-animation: animateThis 1s ease-in;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animateThis {
  0% {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

you can do the same thing on image. Use image class name instead.